# Pressure in open tube

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

[image: img]

In the L shape tube shown in the image shouldn't the pressure at all points A, B,C,D be same as atmospheric pressure?
I have to find relation between A, B, C and D
[image: options]

Comment: Yes, the pressures at A, B, C, and D are atmospheric.  So,....?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "$\omega$" in the drawing suggests that the tube is rotating. In that case there will be a pressure gradient in the horizontal part to provide the centripetal acceleration:

$$
\rho_{\rm air}\omega^2 r = \frac{dP}{dr}
$$

Comment: Shouldn't the water surface in the tank be non-flat, and the depth at D be below the average (rather than above)?

Comment: @ChetMiller Maybe only the tube is rotating and not the entire tank.

Comment: @Tofi That wouldn't produce much of an effect.

Comment: @ChetMiller It would still produce a pressure gradient in the tube because the air inside it would be rotating as well. I think, at equilibrium, the pressure at point A would be equal to atmospheric pressure, and the pressures at points B and C are related to that at A by the equation given in the answer.

Comment: or maybe pressure at point A is related to atmospheric pressure by Bernoulli's equation? idk.

Comment: If air is applying pressure at points A, B and C then their pressure should be more than atmospheric pressure and the air will move out until equilibrium is maintained? Its so confusing

Comment: Is it possible that the water rose up due to excess pressure and that pressure could be the sum of pressures of all 4 points.

Comment: The pressure at A is atmospheric. P at C is below atmosphric and the pressure at D is (P at C) minus $r_{\rm air}gh$, wth $h$ the length of vertical tube between C and D.

Comment: @Tofi I can see it from the perspective of a frame of reference rotating with the tube so that, in the tube, there is artificial gravity in the radial direction.  So the pressure at A would be atmospheric and pressure at C would below atmospheric.

Comment: @mike please explain

Comment: I already have! The tube is rotating so the air is being thrown outwards by "centrifugal force" Theat A is atmospheric, so the   pressure at D is therefore reduced as per the formula I posted.